# SharePoint Designer Workflow Deleted,But still Executing document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

- I have come ac-crossed on rare situation,Where i had written deisnger
  workflow for sharepoint document library.
- And deleted the designer workflow as I see no use of it for my sharepoint
  document library
- But I still see that workflow name is existed as column name in document
  library and it's being executing my document library too .I removed "Cache"   from deisnger ,  But I found no luck.Can any one help me about the issue and how can I solve this

Comment: How you deleted? from library workflow setting?

Comment: Deleted Workflow from SharePoint Designer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that workflow is still attached to library, you can remove this by below steps,

1. Open document library in browser
2. Click on library tab
3. Click on '`Workflow Settings`'. Workflow setting page will be open.
4. Then click on '`Remove, Block, or Restore a Workflow`' link.
5. Select the workflow that you want to remove and click OK.